# Why am I being asked to rebuild buildings?

Tags: civilization-5

When I build a building, say a granary, a couple turns later I have the option to rebuild it. I am wondering whether this is because the building has used its effect and has been consumed? Or just why in general?

Comment: Buildings in cities are never consumed. You may have selected another thing (unit, building, wonder, etc.) for the city to produce while the building was still being built, which will cause the city to pause production on the building to build the select item, and after that item has been produced the game is asking if you'd like to resume building the originally selected building

Comment: @PrivatePansy's answer seem most likely what happened. Or it could be some "glitch", but that's a cop-out answer...

Comment: Are you running any mods or expansions?

Comment: I am not running any different mods, just playing single player. I know I haven't gone to the production tab to start a new building because I am new and just use the choose production prompt. Just basically in a city I have the option to build the same structure multiple times even though I have already build it. Not really a big deal, just wondering if it has effects.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog that asks you to rebuild, or a video of you building and then given the option to build the same building again?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it was a granary?  This sort of thing often occurs with national buildings.

To build the National College, for example, you have to have a Library in every city.  Let's say you start building the National College.  A few turns later, you conquer an opponent's city that doesn't have a Library.  Your National College will stop building, and you'll be prompted to build something else in that city.

If you build (or buy) a Library in your newly-conquered city, you'll get the option to build the National College again.  It'll take your previous progress into account, and start from where you left off.

So you're not being asked to *rebuild* a building, but it might look that way because you'll see the National College again and think "Didn't I already build that?"  It's because you lost the prerequisite condition to build it, but then later obtained that condition again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a deficit?  If you are low on funds it will start selling off units automatically, and maybe it's doing something similar with your buildings?  Unless you sell a building or it gets destroyed in city conquest, buildings are permanent.